# Activating/deactivating a virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I started working on my first python API `hello world` example on Friday on my VPS that is running Ubuntu 14.04. I used python3, created folder, virtualenv, activated it and then electricity went out and my connection broke.

I've left it there, and tried to continue where I stopped. Now, I can't find a way to "get into active" mode (to get that command-line view saying something like

```
(myprojectenv)user@host:~/myproject$
```

I've searched for "deactivate" somewhere in order to re-activate it again, but can't find anything such.

Any help understanding what is proper way of handling Virtualenv's is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to activate you `virtualenv` again. In `bash` you have to `source` the activate file:

```
source myprojectenv/bin/activate
```

Comment: `.` is equivalent to `source`, so a shorter version is `. myprojectenv/bin/activate`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, if someone ends up in similar situation as I did.

Just "activate" your virtualenv again:

```
$source yourenv/bin/activate
```

That will re-activate it, and then you can "deactivate".